# EXPECT_CALL not able to track the calls for methods called from the method under test

Tags: googletest, googlemock

First of all, I'm new to Google test, so please forgive my ignorance, if any.
I'm writing unit tests using google test framework for the below class..

```c++
class MsgHandler
{
    public:
        MsgHandler(){}
        ~MsgHandler(){}
        bool decode_data(unsigned char*, unsigned int,char *);
        bool handle_req_state_data(char *, char *);
};

bool MsgHandler::handle_req_state_data(char *a, char *b)
{
    printf("handle_req_state_data called\n");
    return true;
}

bool MsgHandler::decode_data(unsigned char *a, unsigned int b,char *c)
{
    printf("decode_data called\n");
    handle_req_state_data(c, c);
    return true;
}
```

As a first step, I have created the mock class as below

```c++
class MsgHandlerMock : public MsgHandler
{
    public:
        MsgHandlerMock()
        {
        }

        virtual ~MsgHandlerMock() {}

        MOCK_METHOD(bool, handle_req_state_data, (char *, char *), (const));
        //MOCK_METHOD(int, decode_data, (unsigned char*, unsigned int ,char* ));
    private:
};
```

Below is the test function

```c++
TEST_F(TestClass, test01)
{
    MsgHandlerMock mockObj;

    //EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, decode_data(::testing::_,::testing::_,::testing::_)).Times(1);
    EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, handle_req_state_data(::testing::_,::testing::_)).Times(1);

    mockObj.decode_data(0,0,0);
}
```

My intention of this test is to make sure 'handle_req_state_data' is called when I call 'decode_data' with a certain message. But my test fails with below error

```
decode_data called
handle_req_state_data called
...
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, handle_req_state_data(::testing::_,::testing::_))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] TestClass.test01 (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from TestClass (1 ms total)
```

Can someone help me on how to validate the inner method calls with EXPECT_CALL validators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is not virtual, so can't be overridden by the mock, `decode_data` does not use dynamic dispatch and call the original method `MsgHandler::handle_req_state_data`.

```c++
virtual bool handle_req_state_data(char *, char *);
```

```c++
MOCK_METHOD(bool, handle_req_state_data, (char *, char *), (override));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, @273K. Unfortunately I wont be able to define 'handle_req_state_data' as virtual. Is that the only way forward?

Comment: Not the only way. But the other way will not test the real call `handle_req_state_data` from `decode_data`.

Comment: :-) understood. Thanks.
One correction in the changes you proposed..
`MOCK_METHOD(bool, handle_req_state_data, (char *, char *), (override));` only compiles.
`MOCK_METHOD(bool, handle_req_state_data, (char *, char *), (const, override));` doesnt. And in your answer, MOCK_METHOD has 5 arguments, which is not expected.